# WPF change screen resolution in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I have a WPF Application and when I change my screen resolution to 800 X 600 or other smaller resolutions then, I can not see all my form. I see just up side of my form. How may I overcome this?

```
      <local:WorkControl x:Class="Mzaddress.AddressControl"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mzaddress"
      Title="Adresse" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="840"    
      xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon" 
      Loaded="WorkControl_Loaded" x:Name="myCntl"
      FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Mzaddress.UserControls" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
      local:HelpProvider.HelpParameter="AddressControl">
      <local:WorkControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Why would you change the screen resolution to such small resolution? As a user, I would be upset if an application requires something like this. Moreover, WPF has a great feature that allows to adapt to any resolution. Or I miss something?

Comment: @SteveB some of users are using tablet computers. Therefore , they usually change the resolutions.

Comment: So isn't your question: "How to adapt my application to work on smaller resolutions?"?

Comment: You need to change from using absolute values for the position of elements to a fluid layout. However, without the code that defines the layout we can't help you. A list of `using` statements doesn't help.

Comment: better try to redesign with expression blend as follows:  1. Have a scrollViewer outside and 2. design your form in that and export that xaml 3. finlly add it in your wpfApp (about expression blend please see an expert ) i just can suggest this only

Comment: your forms width height is nothing to do with scrollViews width,height it's like an infinite paper for your form, just set 'auto' for verticle and horizontal properties don't hard code with your 'form's width height

Comment: @Prasad I can see the scrollviewer in my project before the debugging, But  when i debug it then it does not seem..

Comment: is it contained under "Grid" or "stackpanel"?

Comment: @Prasad thnx. I have done it !!

Answer (score 3):

Try this little sample und put your form into such simple ScrollViewer.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
              <Grid Height="600" Width="800" Background="Green"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```